# Filter by joined sub-document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to filter a document by a sub-documents referred property. Assume that I have already created models for each schema. The simplified schemas are the following:

```
const store = new Schema({
    name: { type: String }
})

const price = new Schema({
    price: { type: Number },
    store: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Store'
    },
})

const product = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    prices: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Price'
    }] 
})
/* 
Notation: 
lowercase for schemas: product
uppercase for models: Product
*/
```

As a first approach I tried:

`Product.find({'prices.store':storeId}).populate('prices')`

but this does not work as filtering by a sub-document property is not supported on mongoose.

My current approach is using the aggregation framework. This is how the aggregation looks:

```
{
  $unwind: '$prices'
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'prices',
    localField: 'prices',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'prices'
  }
},
{
  $unwind: '$prices'
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'stores',
    localField: 'prices.store',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'prices.store'
  }
}, // populate
{
  $match: {
    'prices.store._id': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(storeId)
  }
}, // filter by store id
{ $group: { _id: '$id', doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$doc' } }
// Error occurs in $group & $replaceRoot
```

For example, before the last two stages if the record being saved is:

```
{
    name: 'Milk', 
    prices: [
        {store: 1, price: 3.2}, 
        {store: 2, price: 4.0}
    ]
}
```

then the aggregation returned: (notice the product is the same but displaying each price in different results)

```
[ 
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Milk', 
        prices: {
           id: 10,
           store: { _id: 1, name : 'Walmart' }, 
           price: 3.2
        }
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Milk', 
        prices: {
           id: 11,
           store: { _id: 2, name : 'CVS' }, 
           price: 4.0
        },
    }
]
```

To solve this issue I added the last part:

```
{ $group: { _id: '$id', doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } },
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$doc' } }
```

But this last part only returns the following:

```
{
    id: 4,
    name: 'Milk', 
    prices: {
        id: 10,
        store: { _id: 1, name : 'Walmart' }, 
        price: 3.2
    }
}
```

Now `prices` is an object, it should be an array and it should contain all prices (2 in this case).

**Question**

How to return all prices (as an array) with the store field populated and filtered by storeId?

Expected result:

```
{
    id: 4,
    name: 'Milk', 
    prices: [
    {
        id: 10,
        store: { _id: 1, name : 'Walmart' }, 
        price: 3.2
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        store: { _id: 2, name : 'CVS' }, 
        price: 4.0
    }]
}
```

**EDIT**

I want to filter products that contain prices in a given store. It should return the product with its prices, all of them.

Comment: You appear to be contradicting yourself by saying you want to "filter by store" but then you are showing different stores in the output. Also `$lookup` **always** returns an array, so your `$match` following `$lookup` does not do what you think it does or what you claim. I get the feeling you're heavily editing here, and too the point where vital detail has been omitted. You could clarify, and make sure the presented logic is really what you intend.

Comment: I want to filter products that contain the store. For example find all products that have prices in Walmart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally convinced your existing pipeline is the most optimal, but without sample data to work from it's hard to really tell otherwise. So just working onward from what you have:

### Using $unwind

```
var pipeline =  [
    // { $unwind: '$prices' }, // note: should not need this past MongoDB 3.0
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'prices',
        localField: 'prices',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'prices'
     }},
     { $unwind: '$prices' },
     { $lookup: {
        from: 'stores',
        localField: 'prices.store',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'prices.store'
      }},
      // Changes from here
      { $unwind: '$prices.store' },
      { $match: {'prices.store._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(storeId) } },
      { $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        name: { $first: '$name' },
        prices: { $push: '$prices' }
      }}
];
```

The points there start with:

- *Initial `$unwind`* - Should not be required. Only in very early MongoDB 3.0 releases was this ever a requirement to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) an array of values before using `$lookup` on those values.
- *`$unwind` after `$lookup`* - Is always required if you expect a "singular" object as matching, since [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) always returns an array.
- *`$match` after `$unwind`* - Is actually an *"optimization"* for pipeline processing and in fact a requirement in order to *"filter"*. Without [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) it's just a verification that *"something is there"* but items that did not match would not be removed.
- *`$push` in `$group`* - This is the actual part the re-builds the `"prices"`array.

The key point you were basically missing was using [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) for the "whole document" content. You really don't ever want that, and even if you want more than just `"name"` you always want to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) the `"prices"`.

In fact you probably do want more fields than just `name` from the original document, but really you should therefore be using the following form instead.

## Expressive $lookup

An alternate is available with most modern MongoDB releases since MongoDB 3.6, which frankly you should be using at minimum:

```
var pipeline =  [
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'prices',
        let: { prices: '$prices' },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: {
            store: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(storeId),
            $expr: { $in: [ '$_id', '$$prices' ] }
          }},
          { $lookup: {
            from: 'stores',
            let: { store: '$store' },
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$_id', '$$store' ] } }
            ],
            as: 'store'
          }},
          { $unwind: '$store' }
        ],
        as: 'prices'
    }},
    // remove results with no matching prices
    { $match: { 'prices.0': { $exists: true } } }
];
```

So the first thing to notice there is the "outer" `pipeline` is actually just a single [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage, since all it really needs to do is "join" to the `prices` collection. From the perspective of joining to your original collection this is also true since the additional [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in the above example is actually related from `prices` to another collection.

This is then exactly what this new form does, so instead of using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the resulting array and then following on the join, *only* the matching items for "prices" are then "joined" to the "stores" collection, and *before* those are returned into the array. Of course since there is a "one to one" relationship with the "store", this will actually [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

In short, the output of this simply has the original document with a `"prices"` array inside it. So there is no need to re-construct via [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and no confusion of what you use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) on and what you [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

---

> **NOTE**: I'm more than a little suspect of your "filter stores" statement and attempting to match the `store` field as presented in the `"prices"` collection. The question shows expected output from two different stores even though you specify an equality match.
>
> If anything I suspect you *might* mean a *"list of stores"*, which would instead be more like:
>
> ```
> store: { $in: storeList.map(store => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(store)) }
> ```
>
> Which is how you would work with a *"list of strings"* in both cases, using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) for matching against a "list" and the `Array.map()` to work with a supplied list and return each as `ObjectId()` values.
>
> **TIP**: With mongoose you use a "model" rather than working with collection names, and the actual MongoDB collection names is typically the plural of the model name you registered.
>
> So you don't have to "hardcode" the actual collection names for `$lookup`, simply use:
>
> ```
>    Model.collection.name
> ```

The `.collection.name` is an accessible property on all models, and can save you the trouble of remembering to actually name the collection for `$lookup`. It also protects you should you ever change your `mongoose.model()` instance registration in a way which alters the stored collection name with MongoDB.

---

## Full Demonstration

The following is a self contained listing demonstrating both approaches as work and how they produce the same results:

```
const { Schema, Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const storeSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String }
});

const priceSchema = new Schema({
  price: { type: Number },
  store: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Store' }
});

const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  prices: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Price' }]
});

const Store = mongoose.model('Store', storeSchema);
const Price = mongoose.model('Price', priceSchema);
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // Clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Insert working data

    let [StoreA, StoreB, StoreC] = await Store.insertMany(
      ["StoreA", "StoreB", "StoreC"].map(name => ({ name }))
    );


    let [PriceA, PriceB, PriceC, PriceD, PriceE, PriceF]
      = await Price.insertMany(
          [[StoreA,1],[StoreB,2],[StoreA,3],[StoreC,4],[StoreB,5],[StoreC,6]]
            .map(([store, price]) => ({ price, store }))
        );


    let [Milk, Cheese, Bread] = await Product.insertMany(
      [
        { name: 'Milk', prices: [PriceA, PriceB] },
        { name: 'Cheese', prices: [PriceC, PriceD] },
        { name: 'Bread', prices: [PriceE, PriceF] }
      ]
    );


    // Test 1
    {
      log("Single Store - expressive")
      const pipeline = [
        { '$lookup': {
          'from': Price.collection.name,
          'let': { prices: '$prices' },
          'pipeline': [
            { '$match': {
              'store': ObjectId(StoreA._id),  // demo - it's already an ObjectId
              '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$prices' ] }
            }},
            { '$lookup': {
              'from': Store.collection.name,
              'let': { store: '$store' },
              'pipeline': [
                { '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': [ '$_id', '$$store' ] } } }
              ],
              'as': 'store'
            }},
            { '$unwind': '$store' }
          ],
          as: 'prices'
        }},
        { '$match': { 'prices.0': { '$exists': true } } }
      ];

      let result = await Product.aggregate(pipeline);
      log(result);
    }

    // Test 2
    {
      log("Dual Store - expressive");
      const pipeline = [
        { '$lookup': {
          'from': Price.collection.name,
          'let': { prices: '$prices' },
          'pipeline': [
            { '$match': {
              'store': { '$in': [StoreA._id, StoreB._id] },
              '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$prices' ] }
            }},
            { '$lookup': {
              'from': Store.collection.name,
              'let': { store: '$store' },
              'pipeline': [
                { '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': [ '$_id', '$$store' ] } } }
              ],
              'as': 'store'
            }},
            { '$unwind': '$store' }
          ],
          as: 'prices'
        }},
        { '$match': { 'prices.0': { '$exists': true } } }
      ];

      let result = await Product.aggregate(pipeline);
      log(result);
    }

    // Test 3
    {
      log("Single Store - legacy");
      const pipeline = [
        { '$lookup': {
          'from': Price.collection.name,
          'localField': 'prices',
          'foreignField': '_id',
          'as': 'prices'
        }},
        { '$unwind': '$prices' },
        // Alternately $match can be done here
        // { '$match': { 'prices.store': StoreA._id } },

        { '$lookup': {
          'from': Store.collection.name,
          'localField': 'prices.store',
          'foreignField': '_id',
          'as': 'prices.store'
        }},
        { '$unwind': '$prices.store' },
        { '$match': { 'prices.store._id': StoreA._id } },
        { '$group': {
          '_id': '$_id',
          'name': { '$first': '$name' },
          'prices': { '$push': '$prices' }
        }}
      ];

      let result = await Product.aggregate(pipeline);
      log(result);
    }

    // Test 4
    {
      log("Dual Store - legacy");
      const pipeline = [
        { '$lookup': {
          'from': Price.collection.name,
          'localField': 'prices',
          'foreignField': '_id',
          'as': 'prices'
        }},
        { '$unwind': '$prices' },
        // Alternately $match can be done here
        { '$match': { 'prices.store': { '$in': [StoreA._id, StoreB._id] } } },

        { '$lookup': {
          'from': Store.collection.name,
          'localField': 'prices.store',
          'foreignField': '_id',
          'as': 'prices.store'
        }},
        { '$unwind': '$prices.store' },
        //{ '$match': { 'prices.store._id': { '$in': [StoreA._id, StoreB._id] } } },
        { '$group': {
          '_id': '$_id',
          'name': { '$first': '$name' },
          'prices': { '$push': '$prices' }
        }}
      ];

      let result = await Product.aggregate(pipeline);
      log(result);
    }

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})()
```

Which produces the output:

```
Mongoose: stores.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: prices.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: products.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: stores.insertMany([ { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b, name: 'StoreA', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c, name: 'StoreB', __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54d, name: 'StoreC', __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: prices.insertMany([ { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54e, price: 1, store: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54f, price: 2, store: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f550, price: 3, store: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f551, price: 4, store: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54d, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f552, price: 5, store: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f553, price: 6, store: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54d, __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: products.insertMany([ { prices: [ 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54e, 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54f ], _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f554, name: 'Milk', __v: 0 }, { prices: [ 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f550, 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f551 ], _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f555, name: 'Cheese', __v: 0 }, { prices: [ 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f552, 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f553 ], _id: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f556, name: 'Bread', __v: 0 } ], {})
"Single Store - expressive"
Mongoose: products.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'prices', let: { prices: '$prices' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { store: 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b, '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$prices' ] } } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'stores', let: { store: '$store' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': [ '$_id', '$$store' ] } } } ], as: 'store' } }, { '$unwind': '$store' } ], as: 'prices' } }, { '$match': { 'prices.0': { '$exists': true } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f554",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54e",
        "price": 1,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b",
          "name": "StoreA",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "name": "Milk",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f555",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f550",
        "price": 3,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b",
          "name": "StoreA",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "name": "Cheese",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
"Dual Store - expressive"
Mongoose: products.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'prices', let: { prices: '$prices' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { store: { '$in': [ 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b, 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c ] }, '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$prices' ] } } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'stores', let: { store: '$store' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$eq': [ '$_id', '$$store' ] } } } ], as: 'store' } }, { '$unwind': '$store' } ], as: 'prices' } }, { '$match': { 'prices.0': { '$exists': true } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f554",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54e",
        "price": 1,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b",
          "name": "StoreA",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54f",
        "price": 2,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c",
          "name": "StoreB",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "name": "Milk",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f555",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f550",
        "price": 3,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b",
          "name": "StoreA",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "name": "Cheese",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f556",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f552",
        "price": 5,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c",
          "name": "StoreB",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "name": "Bread",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
"Single Store - legacy"
Mongoose: products.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'prices', localField: 'prices', foreignField: '_id', as: 'prices' } }, { '$unwind': '$prices' }, { '$lookup': { from: 'stores', localField: 'prices.store', foreignField: '_id', as: 'prices.store' } }, { '$unwind': '$prices.store' }, { '$match': { 'prices.store._id': 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b } }, { '$group': { _id: '$_id', name: { '$first': '$name' }, prices: { '$push': '$prices' } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f555",
    "name": "Cheese",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f550",
        "price": 3,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b",
          "name": "StoreA",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f554",
    "name": "Milk",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54e",
        "price": 1,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b",
          "name": "StoreA",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
"Dual Store - legacy"
Mongoose: products.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'prices', localField: 'prices', foreignField: '_id', as: 'prices' } }, { '$unwind': '$prices' }, { '$match': { 'prices.store': { '$in': [ 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b, 5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c ] } } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'stores', localField: 'prices.store', foreignField: '_id', as: 'prices.store' } }, { '$unwind': '$prices.store' }, { '$group': { _id: '$_id', name: { '$first': '$name' }, prices: { '$push': '$prices' } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f555",
    "name": "Cheese",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f550",
        "price": 3,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b",
          "name": "StoreA",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f556",
    "name": "Bread",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f552",
        "price": 5,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c",
          "name": "StoreB",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f554",
    "name": "Milk",
    "prices": [
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54e",
        "price": 1,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54b",
          "name": "StoreA",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54f",
        "price": 2,
        "store": {
          "_id": "5c7c79bcc78675135c09f54c",
          "name": "StoreB",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The first approach works but the optimized proposal returns all values with empty prices array. Regarding the confusion of the question I would like to have the products that contain prices from a given store with the document unaltered (all prices in the array not just the ones that match storeId).

Comment: What does the first part in the optimized pipeline does: 

   {
            $match: {
              supermarket: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
              $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$prices'] }
            }
          }

Comment: @DiegoGallegos Added a full listing that shows a working example of both approaches in practice, as well as "single" and "multiple" store matching. That should help you understand this better. They do both indeed work just as the included results show. Note your "all of them" statement is reliant on a product having multiple prices in the "same store". That's the logic **you** presented. I don't think you really want any store filtering at all, so you should experiment with omitting the lines that filter. The code comments should help you do that.